# using git submodule for deployment with circleCI

Tags: heroku, gruntjs, git-submodules, circleci

I have a project which is built using the yeoman angular-fullstack generator. Part of this setup is a grunt 'build' task which creates a `dist` deployment directory.

So I wanted to deploy just that directory to Heroku and thought this would be an actual use for a git submodule. Rather than worrying about pulling down external changes, a submodule allows be to setup the dist directory as a separate repo that I can deploy independently to Heroku.

This all works nicely on localhost where I can cd into the submodule directory after grunt has completed it's build, and then just commit the changes and push them to the submodule's repo. Heroku is watching the repo and automatically deploys.

My problem is that when I tried to do the same thing in CircleCI, I don't seem to be able to `cd` into the submodule directory in order to add/commit/push the built distribution.

One thought is that I run CircleCI off the dist 'repo', but this will require me to include all the test in the repo which I'd prefer not to deploy to heroku.

I'm looking for anyone that:

1. knows how to commit/push just the submodule in CircleCI, or
2. has a better idea of how to deploy the dist directory (only) to Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

update for anyone facing a similar issue. I ended up using the grunt-buildcontrol plugin which takes the dist directory and commits it to a different repo - exactly what I was trying to achieve with submodules.

So after completing a grunt build, I use grunt buildcontrol to push the dist directory to github. My Heroku app watches the master branch and automagically deploys the new version when master updates.